# Executing Python code in VScode outputs Python PATH and project's absolute path to console

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

When I execute a simple `print('Hello world')` by using "Run Python File" in VScode I get this output

```
barakiva@pop-os:~/Development/Educational/Languages/Python/lang$ /usr/bin/python3 
/home/barakiva/Development/Educational/Languages/Python/lang/vars.py Hello world
```

However, opening VScode's integrated console and typing `python3 vars.py` outputs normally with no clutter

```
barakiva@pop-os:~/Development/Educational/Languages/Python/lang$ python3 vars.py
Hello world
```

Comment: This is because vscode does not have its own terminal. It uses the built-in terminal of the system, so when you run Python file, it will first run the command to start the terminal and then run the file.

Answer (score 1):

This happens because the code is run through the **Terminal**.
In short, under the hood, VSCode opens a new terminal and executes the command to run your program using the full path. It's done this way to avoid possible conflicts, if you choose to e.g. use an external terminal with a custom configuration.

VSCode can also display the program output only, via the **Debug Console** (tab to the left from **Terminal**). To do this, you need to create a custom launch configuration.

In the **Run and Debug** tab click **create a launch.json file** (if you don't have one already) and select the Python File template. Then, in `.vscode/launch.json` change property `"console": "integratedTerminal"`, to `"console": "internalConsole"` for the desired configuration. See the complete config below:

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Python: Current File",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${file}",
            "console": "internalConsole",
            "justMyCode": true
        }
    ]
}
```

With this in place, you can run your Python file like before, and see the program output in the **Debug Console**:

[image]

Comment: But isn't that feature for debugging? What about just executing a program instead of debugging it?

Comment: @BarAkiva The only difference is that the console won't open on its own (the terminal does). This can be fixed with `"internalConsoleOptions": "openOnSessionStart"`